A mapping is selected at random from all defined on set A . If the selected mapping is injective, the probability that only one element maps on itself

Now my attempt :
Total mappings $=n\times n\times n.....=n^n$
Since every element maps to only one other element and none is left untouched in injective:
Number of injective mappings $=n(n-1)(n-2)......=n!$
Number of ways that exactly one element  maps on itself within injective mappings:
To select the element that will map on itself:$^5C_1$
Number of ways $=^5C_1×3×3×2×1$
Probability:
$$\cfrac{^5C_1×18}{5!}=\frac{3}{4}$$
But the correct answer given is:$\cfrac{3}{8}$

Where did I go wrong? Where did I overcount? How to solve if not this way?


Where'd you get the $3 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1$ from? Also, have you seen derangements?

Do you know about rencontres numbers?

@hello_123 If in a mapping only element maps on itself. The other four map to remaining four. But it can't have itself so (3-1)(3)(2)?

If only one element maps on to itself, the other $4$ mappings must be deranged.
A derangement of $4$ elements, i.e. a permutation where no element is in its "proper" position (fixed), can be computed by excluding those permutations having one or more fixed elements using the usual principle of inclusion-exclusion (PIE) to yield
$4! - \binom41 3! + \binom42 2! - \binom43 1! + \binom44 0! = 9$
There is a neat formula for easily computing the number of derangements for any number
$D_n$ is equal to the nearest integer to $\frac{n!}{e}$,
so $D_4 = nint(n!/e) = 9$, as we already found out using PIE.
So $Pr = \dfrac{\binom51\cdot 9}{5!} = \dfrac 38$

The issue is with your $3\times 3 \times 2 \times 1$, which I assume you think is the number of complete derangements of four items.  A better calculation would be:

The first item of four can be in any of the other three slots ($3$ ways)
The item which should have been in that slot can either be

in the slot of the first item ($1$ way) in which case

the last two items must the wrong way round ($1$ way)


in the slot of another item ($2$ ways) in which case

the item which should have been in that slot must be in the final slot and its item in the slot intended for the initial item ($1$ way)





making the result $$\dfrac{\,^5C_1×3\times(1\times1 +2 \times 1)}{5!}=\frac{45}{120}=\frac38$$

If you're familiar with cycle notation and cycle structure for permutations you could approach the problem in this way:
There are $5$ ways to pick an element to map to itself. The remaining four elements must go into one $4$-cycle or two disjoint $2$-cycles (otherwise you would end up with another fixed point). There are $(4-1)!=6$ ways to arrange four elements into a $4$-cycle, and $3$ ways to arrange four elements into two disjoint $2$-cycles. So, there are $6+3=9$ ways to arrange four elements so as to give a permutation with no fixed points (among the four elements).
Then the number of ways of getting a permutation on five elements with exactly one fixed point is $5\cdot 9=45$.
And finally the desired probability is $\frac{45}{5!}=\frac38$.
